# jQuery.complete not working in .live

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.delete').live('click', function () {    
        $('#loading').html("<img src='Image-web/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
        var copyofdel = $(this).parents('.img1');
        var code = $(this).parents('.img1').find('.code').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Ajaxpage/Manipulate.aspx",
            data: { del: code, typerequest: "delete" },
            success: function (recieve_msg) {
                $("#main").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                    $('#loading').fadeOut();
                    alert("F");
                    $(copyofdel).hide();//************
                });
            }
        });

    });

});
```

I want to hide img1 class(every this inside their) when user click the ".delete" class.
in the line (******), does not work? before that everything is ok and work,
How to make it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have used `.ajaxComplete`(is there any specific reason behind it?), I think `copyofdel` its not available inside `.ajaxComplete`. Try following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.delete').live('click', function () {    
        $('#loading').html("<img src='Image-web/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
        var copyofdel = $(this).parents('.img1');
        var code = $(this).parents('.img1').find('.code').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Ajaxpage/Manipulate.aspx",
            data: { del: code, typerequest: "delete" },
            success: function (recieve_msg) {
              $('#loading').fadeOut();
              alert("F");
              $(copyofdel).hide();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: your post was benefit for me,my project start to working.
i use $.ajaxcomplete for Whenever an every Ajax request completes.
but i don't know,  $.ajaxcomplete does not work?
I use two $.ajaxcomplete and each event($.ajaxcomplete) was performed separately,  i use more than 1 ($.ajaxcomplete) in one page? and each event Interfere to other,since remove one, and have just one $.ajaxcomplete , it work,
how can i use more 1 event($.ajaxcomplete) in my page?
if i want to use $.ajaxcomplete in my project how can i?

have you any suggestion?

thank again,